# How to perform this date update on my RecyclerView rows?

Tags: android, interface, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-dialogfragment

In my RecyclerView adapter, my rows have TextViews that display dates. If the user clicks the TextView, a DialogFragment is displayed that lets the user pick a time and date, and then a Date is passed back through an interface.

However I don't know how to grab the date back in the onClick method I added to my TextView.

```
public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView dateTextView;
        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            dateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_textview);

            dateTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //I can call my DialogFragment here but then what?
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an interface to communicate with adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView dateTextView;
    private IAdapter adapter;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView, IAdapter adapter) {
        super(itemView);
        dateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_textview);
        this.adapter = adapter;

        dateTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyDialogFragment fragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(getAdapterPosition(), adapter);
                FragmentTransaction ft = v.getContext().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragment.show(ft, "calendarDialog");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The interface which the adapter will need to implement is:

```
interface IAdapter extends Serializable {
    void setDataAt(int index, Calendar date);
    void notifyItemChanged(int index);
}
```

Since adapter already has the `notifyItemChanged` method, you will only need to implement the `setDataAt` method.

Assuming that your Adapter will only contain dates, here is an example:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> implements IAdapter {

    private List<Calendar> dates = new ArrayList<>();

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Calendar> dates) {
        this.dates = dates;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDataAt(int index, Calendar date) {
        dates.add(index, date);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View holderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_holder, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(holderView, this); // notice how we pass this adapter's interface along with the view
    }

    // Include other methods (getItemCount, onBindViewHolder, etc.)
    // Adapter already has the notifyItemChanged(int index) method so no need to override it
}
```

Here is an example of a DialogFragment that uses the index position and a `Calendar` object:

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private int index;
    private IAdapter adapter;


    public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int index, IAdapter adapter) {
        MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        args.putSerializable("adapter", adapter);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        index = args.getInt("index");
        adapter = args.getSerializable("adapter");
    }

    // Build view and set OnClickListener for setting date
}
```

After the user updates the date, invoke the following:

```
adapter.setDataAt(index, date);
adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
```

Comment: I don't understand, the DialogFragment will still have to pass the date back to the underlying activity because it too needs an interface

Comment: @ArukaJ do you need it at the activity level to save it to a database of some sort? Then you can create a `RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver` which will listen to when the data was changed and then you can perform the necessary operations on the database

Comment: The DialogFragment has a Calendar which gets modified by the user. myCalendar.getTime(); is the Date I need access to for the row in the adapter. When the user presses OK on that DialogFragment I have to somehow pass it back.

Comment: @ArukaJ I updated the code to pass a `Calendar` object. The adapter is in charge of handling the data, which is why you need to tell the adapter the position of where the data was updated and what the data was. If you need the activity to know of these changes (in case you want to save to a database) you can do so with a `AdapterDataObserver`

Comment: I am confused again, how would I actually send the Calendar back from the DialogFragment? Where does IAdapter get defined? Where do setDataAt() and notifyItemChanged() get placed?

Comment: @ArukaJ I added an example of the adapter. When creating the DialogFragment, pass the object's index (`getAdapterPosition()`) and the adapter interface to it, so that you can update the date from the fragment

Comment: That's what I'm asking about, though. I'm not familiar with that method of DialogFragment interaction. I'm used to defining interfaces inside the DialogFragment and then implementing them from the Activity. I am unsure how to use this new approach you're mentioning.

Comment: @ArukaJ please look at the DialogFragment example which shows how you would pass the index and adapter interface

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RecyclerView.notifyItemChanged(i);
```

where i is the index of the item to be updated.

Comment: How? The overriden function from the interface has to be placed way back in the underlying Activity

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose a simpler solution: Since the click handler receives the view as parameter, all necessary communication between the recycler adapter and the picker dialogs can be achieved with tags on the view. See here a dialog sequence that allows setting both date and time:

RecyclerAdapter (assume that the array list **encounters** is the data model):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(
        EncounterViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Encounter encounter = encounters.get(position);
    holder.getDate().setText(encounter.getDate());
    holder.getDate().setTag(R.string.tag_adapter, this);
    holder.getDate().setTag(R.string.tag_position, new Integer(position));
    holder.getDate().setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            showDatePickerDialog(view);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View view) {
    DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment(view);
    datePickerFragment.show(((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public void showTimePickerDialog(View view) {
    TimePickerFragment timePickerFragment = new TimePickerFragment(view);
    timePickerFragment.show(((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}

void notifyDateTimeChanged(int position, Calendar calendar) {
    encounters.get(position).setDate(new Timestamp().get(calendar));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

DatePickerFragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener  {

private View view;

DatePickerFragment(View view) {
    this.view = view;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.set(year, month, day);
    (this.view).setTag(R.string.tag_calendar, calendar);
    EncounterRecyclerAdapter adapter = (EncounterRecyclerAdapter) (this.view).getTag(R.string.tag_adapter);
    adapter.showTimePickerDialog(this.view);
}
}
```

TimePickerFragment:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener  {

private View view;

TimePickerFragment(View view)
{
    this.view = view;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
    EncounterRecyclerAdapter adapter = (EncounterRecyclerAdapter) (this.view).getTag(R.string.tag_adapter);
    int position = ((Integer) (this.view).getTag(R.string.tag_position));
    GregorianCalendar calendar = ((GregorianCalendar) (this.view).getTag(R.string.tag_calendar));
    calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hour, minute);
    adapter.notifyDateTimeChanged(position, calendar);
}
}
```